# How to update model from JSP in controller without redirect anywhere?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

The idea is to update object (that is called "elements") on my jsp, when I click a button. My method is

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/addElement/{id}"})
    public String addElement(ArrayList<Element> elements, Model model, @PathVariable("id") int id) {
        elements.add(new Element(service.findById(id)));       
        model.addAttribute("elements", elements);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

I tried making method void, but it didn't work. How can I avoid redirect here?

Comment: your method its a GET or POST? I guess GET but seems confuse what its doing inside

Comment: It's GET for now, but even if I make it a POST, there's no difference.